# should i change the structure of tables after converting to mongodb from mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb

i always using mysql , but i am interested in mongodb , but i don't know how to transfer my db
ex:

student

```
------------        ----------     
name               student_id      
------------        ----------      
james               1
jim                 2


class
------------        ----------
class_name          class_id
------------        ----------
math                1
science             2
computer            3


takeclass
------------        ----------     
student_id           class_id
------------        ----------     
1                     1
1                     2
2                     1
2                     3
```

when i want the class name that jim take , i use the sql

```
select c.class_name 
from student s, class c,takeclass  t
where s.name='jim' and s.student_id=t.student_id and t.class_id =c.class_id
```

should i change it in mongodb like

```
------------        ----------     ----------
student_fname       student_id      takeclass
------------        ----------     ---------- 
james               1                1,2
jim                 2                1,3


class
------------        ----------
class_name          class_id
------------        ----------
math                1
science             2
computer            3

let student=mongoclient.collection('student').findOne({student_fname:"jim"})
let classname=mongoclient.collection('class').find({class_id:{$in:student.class_id.split(',')}})
```

i don't know is it the best way to use mongodb or i shouldn't change the struct and using the other way to query?

Comment: MongoDB is a NoSQL, document-oriented database with a very different approach. First off, you'll need to carefully design a MongoDB schema, which could utilize the best features of MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change the MySQL structure while migrating to MongoDB.
The changed structure you've mentioned above is good enough.

You probably could also include the **class_name** in student's document along with **class_id** in **take_class** to avoid calling another document for searching **class_name**.

If you don't change the structure, using MongoDB will not make any sense as it will behave like a relational DB.
Remember, documents can be nested in MongoDB or any NoSQL DB, and use it to our convenience. This is one of the biggest advantages of using MongoDB over MySQL.

Comment: thank garywinthorpe! , i still  have a problem about put the  class_name in student document  , if the class_name is change , i need to update all the document   that contain the class_name field , should it be happen?